# can i use Bootstrap container class inside row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to know can i use container class inside row. Actually i'm new using bootstrap so i want to know if i use container inside row so it's fine or not

```
  <main class="container-fluid"> 

    <header>
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="navbar dark-r">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a> </div>
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Sign in</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Sign in</button>
                </div>
                <nav class="nav light-r">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
                        <li>Home</li>
                        <li>Home</li>
                        <li>Home</li>
                        <li>Home</li>
                        <li>Home</li>
                        <li>Home</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
</main>
```

i'm also using nav inside nav is this right? or wrong or i have to use div except it.

Comment: You can use however you want to be your layout. But nav inside nav must be thinkable. Why you just not use ul inside nav.

Comment: Yes you can use it. But get an idea about the layout flow and then use it where needed.

Comment: It is not a good practice to use `nav` inside another `nav`.You should follow standard practice all time for simplicity and better coding.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud nav is a blocklevel element. So there is no issue nesting them.

Comment: alright guys anyone can i suggestion me any article where i can get idea about prefect layout flow

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud is it ok if remove nav and use div inside it with the class of nav like  <nav class="navbar"><div class="container"></div><div class="nav">
</div>
</nav>

Comment: @HamzaNisar it depends on your needed.Why you want to use another `<div class="container">` inside a `nav` which is another wrap with another `container` `div` ? There is no problem at all but always try to be standard practice.Please see the documentation where they write details.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use container class inside row class. Since all that container class does is add's 15px padding on sides and centeres itself using margin auto on left and right. Thus there is no reason why you would not be able to use container inside your row class.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes.
Regarding Bootstrap 4:
this is what the .row, .container and .col classes do :

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
.col-{size} {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Remember that .row and .nav classes both turn the direct children into flex items

Answer (score -1):

To answer your second question about using multiple `<nav>` tags, it's better to use the `.nav` class as part of a `<ul>` tag. For example, please see below for a basic navbar which I've pulled from the [W3Schools Bootstrap 3](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp) tutorial which will clearly explain what markup you need to use.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

As you can see, the markup uses a single `<nav>` tag which basically acts as a wrapper for the two `<ul>` tags.

Hope this helps!

P.S - It's not compulsory to use the `.navbar-right` class in the second `<ul>` tag in your markup if you want a different navigation layout!